# Context cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I was developing an app where I'm using hilt to inject some dependencies.

My problem comes when I try to inyect the only activity whih the app have.

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: es.paytef.hioposconnector.MyApplication cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.di.AppModule.provideActivity(AppModule.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.di.AppModule_ProvideActivityFactory.provideActivity(AppModule_ProvideActivityFactory.java:41)
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:579)
                                                                                                        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:443)
                                                                                                        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$1.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:104)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:89)
                                                                                                        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:116)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:87)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:72)
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:70)
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:32)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:261)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:73)
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.ui.theme.ThemeKt.HioPosConnectorTheme(Theme.kt:65)
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:32)
                                                                                                        at es.paytef.hioposconnector.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:31)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:404)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:250)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:249)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:177)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
2023-05-08 16:20:40.418  9940-9940  AndroidRuntime          es.paytef.hioposconnector            E      at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3248)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3173)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:587)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:950)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1060)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1147)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:17498)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3339)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3346)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3346)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3346)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3346)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1684)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1408)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6781)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
2023-05-08 16:20:40.422  9940-9940  AndroidRuntime          es.paytef.hioposconnector            E      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6756)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

And regarding my AppModule is the following:

AppModule.kt:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {
    private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    //If it needed add interceptor in the instance of httpClient above.

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideActivity(@ApplicationContext context: Context):Activity{
        return context as Activity
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
        context.getSharedPreferences(
            "shared_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCodigoQRODeBarrasApi(): CodigoQRODeBarrasApi {
    return ApiClient(okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient, converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()).createService(CodigoQRODeBarrasApi::class.java)
    }
```

Do you know some way to create Activity instance without casting from context, which seems doens't works.

Thanks in advance !

[EDIT]

So I change to use an ActivityModule like that:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class ActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideActivity(@ActivityContext activity: Activity): Activity {
        return activity
    }
}
```

And now I'm getting the following error despite I'm using @Inject annotation in the 2 classes where I inyect Activity:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.app.Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FragmentGetContextFix.FragmentGetContextFixEntryPoint,
                         ^
      android.app.Activity is injected at
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(activity: Activity, sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) :ViewModel() {

    private val request = HioPosRequest.forIntent(activity.intent, activity)

    init {
...
...
}
```

CustomParamsUsecase.kt

```
@ActivityRetainedScoped
class CustomParamsUsecase @Inject constructor(
    sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
    val request : HioPosRequest,
    val activity: Activity
) {

....
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're trying to cast `Application` to `Activity`:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideActivity(@ApplicationContext context: Context):Activity{
    return context as Activity
}
```

You cannot do like this, because `Application` is not an incestor of `Activity`.

There are 2 things to mention about your solution:

1. You shouldn't inject `Activity` to objects marked as `@Singleton`. `Activity` has a lifecycle and this solution will cause memory leaks in your Application.
2. Also you shouldn't inject `Activity` to dependencies in a module in `@SingletonComponent`. This may cause memory leaks too.

**Instead, you have to:**

1. Create a module marked which is being used by `@ActivityComponent`, not `@SingletonComponent`.
2. Provide Activity with `@ActivityContext` annotation, not `@ApplicationContext`

   ```
    @Module
    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
    object MyActivityModule {

        @Provides
        fun provideMyObject(@ActivityContext activity: Context): MyObject {
            return MyObject(activity = activity as Activity)
        }

    }
   ```

**Update**

If you want to use Activity like this, you need to change your module:

```
    @Provides
    fun provideActivity(@ActivityContext activity: Context): Activity {
        return activity
    }
```

Also this problem can be caused, because dependencies of `ActivityComponent` will not be found in `SingletonComponent`. You can read it in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-hierarchy) in more details.

Comment: I update my question changing as you say

Comment: I get same error

Comment: Provide the full code please. In your current code that I see you're using Activity which is declared in module from `ActivityComponent` in objects which are declared in `SingletonComponent` which is impossible as I said

Comment: Regarding modules the full code is posted, and the class where I'm inyect it, have the code where I'm passing the dependecy